# Why does VPN break my internet connection?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, vpn, isp

Recently I bought internet service from an alternative ISP.

I don't really know if I can trust them, so everything that is unimportant and not private, I browse without encryption, but what I value, I do over ZenMate (Chromium's addon).

However, looks this this encryption on my Ubuntu PC causes the WiFi connection to fail about 7 out of 10 times.

When I ping my router, everything is fine.
When I ping Google's DNS, everything is fine.

So how can I determine if my ISP doesn't want me to use encryption, or maybe the problem might be in something I don't take into account?

Comment: Just, how do you launch ZenMate? With a browser extension? A separate VPN client app? Please update your original question above to include the answers.

Comment: What fails? You say it fails, then list 2 things that are working. Can you tell us something that is not working?

Comment: Connection breaks when I start using Zenmate. I go to firefox browser and type www.bing.com and it doesn't connect. I go to terminal in linux and type ping 204.79.197.200 and I get response.

Answer (score 0):

A web search for "[is the internet down for me or everyone?](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=lm&q=is+the+internet+down+for+me+or+everyone%3F)" reveals some sites that should check websites and answer that question... of course, you need access to the internet to access these sites, so *catch-22*-ish

To just check whether or not your VPN is down, and/or your direct internet connection, pinging different sites is a good idea. If you have your VPN setup so you can ping through it, you can compare the results with your direct internet results.

On linux I use a "fancy" ping program like `mtr`, it's in the repos for [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/mtr), [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/stable/net/mtr), [fedora](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/mtr) very likely any linux:

```
   mtr combines the functionality of the traceroute and ping programs in a
   single network diagnostic tool.

   As mtr starts, it investigates the network connection between the  host
   mtr  runs on and HOSTNAME.  by sending packets with purposely low TTLs.
   It continues to send packets with low TTL, noting the response time  of
   the  intervening  routers.   This allows mtr to print the response per‐
   centage and response times of the internet route to HOSTNAME.  A sudden
   increase  in  packet  loss or response time is often an indication of a
   bad (or simply overloaded) link.

   The results  are  usually  reported  as  round-trip-response  times  in
   miliseconds and the percentage of packetloss.
```

You should be able to test whether or not your regular direct internet connection really goes down when you use the VPN (unless your ISP were cutting you off for using the VPN, or maybe your router were getting "overwhelmed" with traffic and slowing down/freezing...) or if it's just the VPN that is down.

Comment: So what would be the easiest way (I'm not a superGeek) to figure this out with mtr ? Pinging and getting response from DNS can be done if the internet is down ?

Comment: The dns server (which could be "local" to your ISP, so might work if the "wider" internet is down) gives you the ip address of a website. If you can successfully ping the website, you're connecting directly to it, so the internet is up (at least to that website). I think Google's dns servers are somewhere on the "wider" internet. But I'm not sure how to ping through your VPN, it could be tricky or even impossible to setup, but using your VPN web browser to connect to a webpage tells you if it's up too

Comment: When I use encryption and it drops I cannot browse sites neither on VPN or directly but I still can ping whatever site I want.

Comment: Hmm... pinging a site should mean it's up & you can reach it. Maybe your browser gets configured to use the VPN, and isn't using the direct ISP connection if/when the VPN is down/off? Sometimes there's a separate browser or profile just for the VPN, like there's the Tor Browser Bundle that only uses tor, leaving your regular browser for direct connections. but I don't know how your is set up

Comment: Two separate browsers one with encrypting add-on other without. Internet drops when using the one that encrypts. And sometimes connection comes back when I simultaneously try to browse sites with the one that doesn't encrypt. Weird.

Comment: Possibly a general WiFi connection issue... sometimes mine works better if I keep pinging a big site (like youtube/google), might keep the link "alive"